# RTL - Why the border-right is not changing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying right to left direction in my HTML as it will be useful for languages like arabic,hebrew

The problem which i face is border-right is not changing it's retained in the same place when shifted to RTL. According to my understanding i thought border-right will be changed as border-left when i switch to RTL mode.

What does RTL property really does?. It just shifts only the content.
If so i can do the workaround by changing the border-right to left in case of RTL. But before doing that i just to want understand what the RTL really does. Please throw some light on it

```js
var rtl = document.getElementById('RTL');
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var currentState;
rtl.onclick = implementRTL;

function implementRTL() {
  currentState = content.getAttribute('dir');
  if (currentState == 'ltr') {
    content.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
  } else {
    content.setAttribute('dir', 'ltr');
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 10px solid #000;
  border-right: 10px solid red
}
```

```html
<div id="content" dir="ltr">
  Hi Here is the content
</div>
<button id="RTL">
  RTL SWITCH
</button>
```

Check the code below which i tried

Comment: It seems that whole box property like padding,border,margin is not supporting

Comment: No, element at right dont switch left when RTL is defined, it just align the text..

Comment: `dir` doesn't transform the entire element or page, it's just sets direction or flow of page and it's content.

Answer (score 5):

### [`border-inline-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-inline-end)

This property sets the right border when the text is LTR and the left border in case of RTL. Similarly, there is `border-inline-start` for the border on the other side, and `border-block-start` and `border-block-end` for the top and bottom borders. They apply correctly to vertical text as well.

```js
var rtl = document.getElementById('RTL');
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var currentState;
rtl.onclick = implementRTL;

function implementRTL() {
  currentState = content.getAttribute('dir');
  if (currentState == 'ltr') {
    content.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
  } else {
    content.setAttribute('dir', 'ltr');
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 10px solid #000;
  /* border-right: 10px solid red; */ /* old */
  border-inline-end: 10px solid red; /* new */
}
```

```html
<div id="content" dir="ltr">
  Hi Here is the content
</div>
<button id="RTL">
  RTL SWITCH
</button>
```

Comment: But the bad news is...it's supported only in firefox

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Yeah, that's what I wrote. Shame.

Comment: Nowadays it works for all the browsers, updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`dir="ltr"` sets the direction of content flow within a block-level element. This applies to text, inline, and inline-block elements. It also sets the default alignment of text and the direction that table cells flow within a table row.

You can use `direction: rtl;` in CSS and do something like that :

```
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
.element {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.rtl .element {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

or

```
.element {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
#content:dir(rtl) .element { 
  border-right: none;
  border-left: 1px solid red; 
}
```

Comment: I very well know the work around dude...I just want to know what RTL really does

Comment: Well I gave you an explanation just before. In a sense I understand your point, it'd be so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

When the "dir" attribute of content reflects a value of either *ltr* or *rtl*, what gets effected is the direction in which text displays. Altering the border-color of an element generally requires a manual solution. Here is one way to accomplish this feat:

HTML:

```
<div id="content" dir="ltr">
  Hi! Here is the content
</div>
<button id="RL">
  RL SWITCH
</button>
```

CSS:

```
div,.divltr {
  border: 10px solid #000;
  border-right: 10px solid red;
}

.divrtl {
  border: 10px solid #000;
  border-left: 10px solid red;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;

var rl = d.g('RL');
var c = d.g('content');
rl.addEventListener('click',function(){
  toggleWhichWay();
}); 

function setTextBorder(whichway) {
  c.setAttribute('dir', whichway);
  c.className = "div" + whichway;
}

function getCurrState() {
  return c.getAttribute('dir');
}

function toggleWhichWay() {
  (getCurrState() == 'ltr')? setTextBorder('rtl') :setTextBorder('ltr');
}
```

see [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbKKgN).

Answer (score -1):

```
var toggleButton = document.querySelector('#rtl');
var targetEle = document.querySelector('#content');
function toggleTextDir(ele) {
    var dir = ele.attributes.dir.value;
    ele.attributes.dir.value = dir === 'rtl' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl';
}
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
     toggleTextDir(targetEle);
});
```

Comment: [https://fiddle.jshell.net/hf7kjpm2/] (https://fiddle.jshell.net/hf7kjpm2/)

Comment: Instead of posting a code without any explanation, and being [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) - read the question: **RTL - Why the border-right is not changing**